# tikz graphics do not show up though text does

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a new (Jan 2018) Ubuntu 16.04 linux distribution on a new laptop with what I presume is the standard texlive that came with it.

On running pdflatex on the following file these are the first few lines:

> pdflatex testtikz.tex
>   This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
>    restricted \write18 enabled.
>   entering extended mode
>   (./testtikz.tex
>   LaTeX2e <2016/02/01>

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}

    \begin{document}

    PGF version is \pgfversion

    Before tikzpic

   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw (0,0) -- (0,2) -- (2,0)-- (0,0);
   \filldraw[color=red!60, fill=red!5, very thick](-1,0) circle (1.5);
   \node (maintopic) {Text};
   \end{tikzpicture}

   After tikzpic

   Regular latex picture follows:

   \setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
   \thicklines
   \begin{picture}(10,6)
   \put(2,2.2){\line(1,0){6}}
   \put(2,2.2){\circle{2}}
   \put(6,2.2){\oval(4,2)[r]}
   \end{picture}

   \end{document}
```

The tikz graphics do not show up in the output (screenshot below), though tikz appears to be functioning since the \node command generates text. I have not used tikz before, though have used latex for typesetting for many years. Instead of pdflatex, I tried latex; still no graphics showing up on xdvi nor after dvipdf.

[image: Output file]

What is wrong with my attempt to use tikz?

Comment: For me, your code compiles without an error, and the `tikzpicture` is displayed.

Comment: Weird. My system is the same as yours (Ubuntu 16.04, Texlive 2015, pgf 3.0.1a). My guess is that it is a viewer problem, since the code compiles for you and there is the space for the tikzpicture. What pdf viewer do you use?

Comment: Thanks for the note. I used acroread, evince and xpdf all with the same result. Even printed it out on paper. Looks the same if I try the dvi output and xdvi.

Comment: Also tried it on an old laptop, Ubuntu 14, Texlive 2013, PGF 2.01 with the same result, with evince, xpdf, gs viewer.